# Android's ListView doesn't show content after changing orientation

Tags: android-listview, android-contentprovider

I use a content provider to display data from a database. The content is shown in a ListActivity. When I change the orientation of the phone, sometimes it won't reload the data and shows an empty ListView. What could be the reason? It happens about every 4-5th time...
There's an actionbar spinner that has three items: Show All, Show Date, Show Location which will query the db to only show a subset

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
private  Cursor mCursor = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSimpleCursorAdapter = new SpecialAdapter(this, 
        R.layout.row,
        null,
        PROJECTION,
        new int[] { R.id.titleID, R.id.dateTimeOrLocationID1 , R.id.dateTimeOrLocationID2 },
        CursorAdapter.NO_SELECTION);

   //mListView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
   //mListView.setAdapter(mSimpleCursorAdapter);
   setListAdapter(mSimpleCursorAdapter);
   mOnNavigationListener = new OnNavigationListener() {

      @Override
      public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int position, long itemId) {

          switch(position) { 
          case 0:
              mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ReminderContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
              break;
          case 1:
              mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ReminderContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, " Date NOT NULL", null, null);
              break;
          case 2:
              mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ReminderContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, " Address NOT NULL", null, null);
              break;
          default:
              break;
          }
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, MainActivity.this);
        return true;
      }
    };
}

@Override
 public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0,  null,  this);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    int showWhat = prefs.getInt(Utils.PREF_SHOW_ALL_DATE_OR_ADDRESS, 1);
    VisibilitySelection enumValue = VisibilitySelection.values()[showWhat-1];

    switch (enumValue) {
    case SHOW_ALL:
        mShowProperty = VisibilitySelection.SHOW_ALL;
        break;
    case SHOW_DATE_TIME:
        mShowProperty = VisibilitySelection.SHOW_DATE_TIME;
        break;
    case SHOW_ADDRESS:
        mShowProperty = VisibilitySelection.SHOW_ADDRESS;
        break;
    default:
        mShowProperty = VisibilitySelection.SHOW_ALL;
        break;
    }
    getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
}

@Override
 public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    CursorLoader loader = null;
    switch(mShowProperty) {
   case SHOW_ALL:
        loader = new CursorLoader(this, ReminderContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, null);
        break;
    case SHOW_DATE_TIME:
        loader = new CursorLoader(this, ReminderContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, " Date NOT NULL", null, null);
        break;
    case SHOW_ADDRESS:
        loader = new CursorLoader(this, ReminderContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, " Address NOT NULL", null, null);
        break;
    }
    return loader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mSimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mSimpleCursorAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
}
```

Comment: That `onCreate` signature is wrong. Should be `public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)` and you should be calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)` inside. Also, you can just use `setListAdapter` from `ListActivity`.

Comment: thanks, I edited the code. This doesn't solve the problem though. Any ideas why it doesn't reload the items when changing orientation?

Comment: Well, it could be that the double-restart (once in `onStart`, once in `onResume`) is messing it up. Remove the one in `onResume` and change the call in `onStart` to `initLoader()`, which should reconnect to an existing Loader. Also, you're not calling `super.onStart()`.

Comment: this solved the problem! Any idea why the double-restart could mess it up? Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's not how you're supposed to use it. :) I don't know what more you might need as an explanation..